# explain the bitwise opeartors use in canvas imagedata pixel color assignment

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

First The code:

```
    data[y * canvasWidth + x] =
        (255   << 24) | // alpha
        (value << 16) | // blue
        (value <<  8) | // green
         value;     // red
    }
```

I am trying to reunderstand this, i once had. But then i forgot. I found it again in this article: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-ty

This code in use: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewjbaker/Fnx2w/

### My Questions:

- What does << and | do here, what do they accomplish and for what?
- How combining all rbga values together work here?

Links:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8ClampedArray
3. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint32Array
4. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators
5. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData

Comment: it lets you put 4 numbers into one integer, so the resulting array is 1/4th the length. this can make some operations faster, and reduce the footprint of the image data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code tries to pack the values in 32 bits. Try to understand it like this

```
(255 << 24) | (value << 16) | (value << 8) | value;
```

So first, 255 left shifted 24 times. So, the binary value becomes like this

```
1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Then, whatever the value of `value`, is left shifted by 16 and then `or`ed with the already gotten value. Lets assume that the `value` is also 255. So, 255 << 16 will be

```
0000 0000 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

So, when we do bitwise `or`, the value becomes

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Now, we packed two values in it. The same way, all the values will be packed as a 32 bit number.

---

Simply packing is half the story. What if I want to get the REG value? We use masks and bitwise AND operator, like this.

```
(colorValue & (255 << 24)) >> 24
```

This will give the 8 bit red value. We just enable the right most 8 bits in a 32 bit number and all others are set to 0. So, when we do `&` with the actual value, we will get the bits enabled in those 8 bits corresponding to the mask. And then we right shift by 24 to push the 24 bits off the boundary and only the actual red value will remain.

Similarly, you can get the green value, like this

```
(colorValue & (255 << 16)) >> 16
```

and blue

```
(colorValue & (255 << 8)) >> 8
```

and the last value with simply

```
(colorValue & 255)
```

#### Example

Lets say,

```
var colorValue = 2131637306;
```

The bit representation is

```
0111 1111 0000 1110 0011 0100 0011 1010
```

So, when we do

```
console.log(colorValue & (255 << 24));
# 2130706432
```

whose binary representation is

```
0111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

and when we do

```
console.log((colorValue & (255 << 24)) >> 24);
# 127
```

binary representation is

```
 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0111 1111
```

Similarly, all the values can be retrieved.

As @GameAlchemist mentions in the comments section, the masks are normally represented in HexaDecimal to understand this clearly, like this

```
var redMask   = 0xFF000000,
    greenMask = 0x00FF0000,
    blueMask  = 0x0000FF00,
    valueMask = 0x000000FF;
```

Comment: loud and clear, but for the 'read' part, i found clearer, and it's faster if the js engine is stupid, to use red = colorValue & 0xFF0000; green= colorValue & 0x00FF00; blue = colorValue & 0x0000FF

Comment: @GameAlchemist Thanks :-) Included that in the answer.

Comment: just to be clear and complete can you also explain how this packing fits with canvas... `ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h).data`  returns dataView typed `Uint8ClampedArray`. Then `Uint32Array` typed dataView is used to store data..So what's a difference between them?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer I am really sorry, I have no idea about Canvas. I only knew about this bitwise-packing :'(

Comment: I don't think you have to know about canvas, if you just knew about Unit8... and Unit32...and why unit32 is used, i suspect it's for packing purpose only

Comment: I posted some links, either way.. i am very thankful for your answer.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer : You can have any type of view on a byte buffer : you can have them treated as 8,16, 32 bit signed or unsigned integer Arrays + the 32/64 float views + the clamped view . See this tutorial about the typed array, from html5rocks : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/typed_arrays/

Comment: @MuhammadUmer JavaScript numbers are normally 64 bit numbers. But we need only 32 bits to work here, so that we can save memory. That is they would be using 32 bit types. Also, the last bit in the numbers are generally used to denote the sign of the number (+ve/-ve). But we don't need that here. If we use that, we would be left with only 31 bits. So, to ignore the sign bit, they use UInt (unsigned int).

Comment: !!!Important notice !!! If using a 32 bit view on an image byte buffer, the endianness enter into account, and to make it short, you have to reverse the rgba mask order (it's abgr on 99.99999% of devices)

Comment: what happens to value, if they were assigned by using `Uint32` but read from the same buffer using `Uint8`?